# Saving values using variable_set through an array

Tags: configuration

I have used `variable_set` to save one value. How can I save multiple values through an array using `variable_set`?

Answer (score 11):

It's the same:

The [`variable_set`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) function saves the variable to database serializing it. `variable_get` takes the variable from `$conf` where the variable is already unserialized.

Example:

```
$var1 = array(
 'key1' => 'value1',
 'key2' => 'value2'
);
variable_set('var1', $var1);
print_r variable_get('var1');
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it, just pass an array to `variable_set`. Although perhaps a consequence of brevity and example, do remember to pass a default value of the expected data type to `variable_get` as the second parameter, e.g `$var1 = variable_get('var1', array());`

Comment: the second parameter in variable_get is optional on D7.

Comment: Optional, but recommended. For example, imagine you're going to `foreach` over that variable and it's empty for some reason, you would then `foreach` over NULL and trigger a PHP notice error whereas passing `array()` as the expected default value data type will avoid such an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you wand do it in the system form, you can use #tree param.

```
    $settigs = variable_get('default_settings', array(
      'setting_1' => NULL,
      'setting_2' => NULL,
    ));
    $form['default_settings'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('Default settings'),
      '#weight' => 5,
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
      '#tree' => TRUE
    );
    $form['default_settings']['setting_1'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Setting 1'),
      '#default_value' => $settings['setting_1'],
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
    $form['default_settings']['setting_2'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Setting 2'),
      '#default_value' => $settings['setting_2'],
      '#required' => TRUE
    );
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to save an array with `variable_set()`. Your answer doesn't explain that. since using that code would still require you to call `variable_set()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way to save array value in varible_set(); is json. drupal_json_encode() and drupal_json_decode() function in drupal 7.

You can do something like this:-

```
$var_input = array(
 'key1' => 'value1',
 'key2' => 'value2'
);
$var_input = json_encode($var_input);  // convert to json

variable_set('var1', $var_input); // set in variable

$var_output = variable_get('var1'); // get from variable

$var_output = drupal_json_decode($var_output); // decode json

print_r($var_output);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: No need to save as JSON, especially when `variable_get` is called and used in PHP just set the variable with `variable_set` and pass an array. That way, an array will be returned with `variable_get` automatically ready for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) there isn't any difference between saving a persistent variable containing a string or an array, since it passes its `$value` parameter to `serialize()`.

```
db_merge('variable')->key(array('name' => $name))->fields(array('value' => serialize($value)))->execute();
```

Eventually, what changes for you is what you do when the saved value comes from a form. To make it easier for you to save an array, you could use a form with the following structure.

```
  $options = variable_get('admin_theme', array());
  $form['admin_theme'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Administration theme'),
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['admin_theme']['admin_theme'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(0 => t('Default theme')) + $theme_options,
    '#title' => t('Administration theme'),
    '#description' => t('Choose "Default theme" to always use the same theme as the rest of the site.'),
    '#default_value' => $options['admin_theme'],
  );
  $form['admin_theme']['node_admin_theme'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Use the administration theme when editing or creating content'),
    '#default_value' => $options['node_admin_theme'],
  );
```

In the submission handler, you can then save the settings with `variable_set('admin_theme', $form_state['values'][admin_theme'])`.